# Dynamically create a configuration file and add it as a configmap in k8s using terraform

Tags: terraform

I want to generate a sudoers file dynamically using a terraform and here the usernames will get changed based on the requirement.

so my final sudoers file should look like below.

Sudoers file:

```
# This file MUST be edited with the 'visudo' command as root.
#
# Please consider adding local content in /etc/sudoers.d/ instead of
# directly modifying this file.
#
# See the man page for details on how to write a sudoers file.
#
Defaults        env_reset
Defaults        mail_badpass
Defaults        secure_path="/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/snap/bin"

# Host alias specification

# User alias specification

# Cmnd alias specification
Cmnd_Alias USRCMDS = /usr/sbin/service ssh restart, /usr/bin/passwd
# User privilege specification
root    ALL=(ALL:ALL) ALL

# Members of the admin group may gain root privileges
%admin ALL=(ALL) ALL

# Allow members of group sudo to execute any command
%sudo   ALL=(ALL:ALL) ALL

# See sudoers(5) for more information on "#include" directives:

#includedir /etc/sudoers.d
**<username1>** ALL=(root) NOPASSWD: /usr/sbin/service ssh restart, /usr/bin/passwd **<username1>**
**<username2>** ALL=(root) NOPASSWD: /usr/sbin/service ssh restart, /usr/bin/passwd **<username2>**
**<username3>** ALL=(root) NOPASSWD: /usr/sbin/service ssh restart, /usr/bin/passwd **<username3>**
```

As you see in the above file, username1,2, 3 etc.. are passed as a variable(these usernames are list of strings and these user are get passed to the tf externally) to terraform script.

I'm tiring to use tpl to generate this sudoers file and create a k8s config map using terraform.

I tried following code snippet to achieve this but it is not working.

**.tf file:**

```
    data "template_file" "sudoers" {
        count = "${length(var.members_new)}"
        template = "${file("${path.module}/tpl/sudoers.tpl")}"
        vars = {
            members  = "${var.members_new[count.index % length(var.members_new)]}"
        }
    }
    
    resource "kubernetes_config_map" "f1ai_sudoers" {
        count = "${length(var.members_new)}"
        depends_on = [ helm_release.project ]
        metadata {
            name = "sudoers-cm"
            namespace = kubernetes_namespace.project.metadata.0.name
        }
    
        data = {
            "sudoers" = data.template_file.sudoers.rendered
        }
    }
```

**Values.tf:**

```
    variable "members_new" {
        type = list
        default = ["username1", "username2", "username3"]
    }
```

Please help suggest the best way to implement this.

Comment: " but it is not working" - is not specific. What **exactly** is happening? Any error messages? Where does the error occur precisely.

Answer (score 0):

I got the solution for it. This is can be achieved by using a combination of `kubernetes_config_map` tf resource and EOF.

Please find the working code snippet below.

```
resource "kubernetes_config_map" "f1ai_sudoers" {
  depends_on = [ helm_release.project ]
  metadata {
    name = "sudoers-cm"
    namespace = kubernetes_namespace.project.metadata.0.name
  }
  data = {
  "sudoers" = <<EOF
Defaults        env_reset
Defaults        mail_badpass
Defaults        secure_path="/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/snap/bin"

Cmnd_Alias USRCMDS = /usr/sbin/service ssh restart, /usr/bin/passwd
# User privilege specification
root    ALL=(ALL:ALL) ALL

# Members of the admin group may gain root privileges
%admin ALL=(ALL) ALL

# Allow members of group sudo to execute any command
%sudo   ALL=(ALL:ALL) ALL

#includedir /etc/sudoers.d
%{ for username in var.members_new ~}
${username} ALL=(root) NOPASSWD: /usr/sbin/service ssh restart, /usr/bin/passwd ${username}
%{ endfor ~}
   EOF
 }
}
```